# Custom exception for string that is too long

Tags: java, validation, exception

This is my first time working with Java exceptions. I have made a program that works to specifications, but I am wondering if there is anything I've done which is unconventional or not recommended. The application program does specify that there be line breaks between each message.

My driver is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws StringTooLongException{
        String str1;
        final int MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 20;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter strings, enter DONE when finished:\n");
        str1 = input.nextLine();
        if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))
            System.exit(0); //exit on first prompt
        do{
            try
            {
                if(str1.length()>MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
                    throw new StringTooLongException();
                System.out.println("\nEnter a string, enter DONE when finished:\n");
                str1 = input.nextLine();            
            }
                catch(StringTooLongException e)
            {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    str1 = input.nextLine();
            }
        }while(!str1.equalsIgnoreCase("done"));
        input.close();
    }
}
```

And my custom exception class is:

```
public class StringTooLongException extends Exception {
    public StringTooLongException()
    {
        super("\nString has too many characters\n\nPlease try again:\n");       
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))
>         System.exit(0); //exit on first startup
> ```

Do not use `System.exit()` (somewhere else then in a catch block in `main`) It terminates the JVM immediately. This is usually not intended.
just write a `return` instead.

> ```
>          if(str1.length()>MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
>                 throw new StringTooLongException();
>             System.out.println("\nEnter a string, enter DONE when finished:\n");
>             str1 = input.nextLine();
> ```

This will result in an endless loop when the user enters a long string. The check is done (and the exception thrown) before she gets a chance to enter a new one.

You should move the if behind the input request and delete the initial input request (along wit the if there) before the loop.

---

Since you do nothing else in the loop the checking the string and requesting new one some may argue that you use the Exception as *flow control* for which exceptions are not supposed to be used.
I'd agree to that argument in this particular case as long as the "happy path" also repeats the loop...

Comment: Another reason why it's better to use `return` instead of `System.exit`:  `System.exit` prevents the finalizers in the main method (and other parts of the stack) from being called, resulting in a less than clean cleanup

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>         String str1;
> ```

Delete that and change

> ```
>         str1 = input.nextLine();
> ```

to

```
        String str1 = input.nextLine();
```

instead.

> ```
>         if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))
>             System.exit(0); //exit on first prompt
>         do{
>             try
>             {
>                 if(str1.length()>MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
>                     throw new StringTooLongException();
>                 System.out.println("\nEnter a string, enter DONE when finished:\n");
>                 str1 = input.nextLine();            
>             }
>                 catch(StringTooLongException e)
>             {
>                     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
>                     str1 = input.nextLine();
>             }
>         }while(!str1.equalsIgnoreCase("done"));
> ```

This seems the long way around.  Why not

```
        while (!str1.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
            if (str1.length() > MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
            {
                System.out.println("\nString has too many characters\n\nPlease try again:");
            }

            System.out.println("\nEnter a string, enter DONE when finished:\n");
            str1 = input.nextLine();
        }
```

It's uncommon to throw an exception in a `try` block that you catch immediately.  And it's totally unnecessary in this case.  The only thing that you do differently is to print a message.

While not unknown, it is uncommon to put a `try`/`catch` in a loop.  It's extra overhead that you don't need in this case.

It's unclear why you `exit` before the loop.  You can just use a regular `while` loop and exit normally.  You also close `input` in that case.

Comment: It was unclear to me too. After I corrected my mistake, moving the if statement behind the input request, I no longer had the problem of being unable to enter done to exit the loop on the first execution. The exercise actually required a try/catch and throw to be used. I agree though, the if statement is much easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `StringTooLongException` a subclass of `RuntimeException` instead of `Exception` to make it an unchecked exception, in the spirit similar to the unchecked `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and `ArithmeticException`. However, this depends on the API you are willing to present to your users, and whether you think that this exception must be handled specially over others.